# Liferay instanceable portlet does not work properly

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I created a custom instanceable portlet, setting the *instanceable* property to *true*:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>portletFiltriPTF</portlet-name>
    <instanceable>true</instanceable>       
    <header-portlet-javascript>/js/mediolanumadvice/portletFiltriPTF.js</header-portlet-javascript>
</portlet>
```

The problem is that I am able to insert the portlet multiple times inside the same page, but only in one of that the content is visible, as you can see in the following image:

[image: Instanceable portlet]

Is there anything that I have to do in addition to set that property?

Thank you all,
Marco

Answer (score 4):

Two things to check:

- You might have a portlet on page that's (still) non-instanceable because you've added it before you've made your portlet instanceable. They now have different IDs and need to be removed from the page
- You might use IDs that are conflicting - e.g. if both portlets create content with the same ID, they'll end up in the DOM. Use these for formatting or any treatment through JS and weird things happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help the original poster, but in case anyone else comes across this...

My project is using React and we mount our React root to an element with a static id, referred to as the html root, in index.jsp.

When you try to instantiate multiple instances of the same portlet on one page, subsequent instances will not render because there are multiple elements with the same id.

The solution for this is to create an instance id of your own and create a new element to replace the html root, so that the html root becomes something of a placeholder. Since the html element is removed every time you add a portlet instance, you can reliably mount your React root multiple times without issue.

Here you can see a util I wrote to create a unique root and replace the placeholder (I call it RootUtil):

```
export default { 

makeId: function(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < length; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
},

renderRoot: function(placeholderId) {

    // create unique id
    var instanceId = this.makeId(10);
    var id = "react-root-instance-" + instanceId;

    // create unique root
    var root = document.createElement("div");
    root.setAttribute("id", id);

    // find placeholder
    const placeholder = document.getElementById(placeholderId);

    // replace placeholder
    //placeholder.replaceWith(root); **breaks in IE**
    placeholder.parentElement.replaceChild(root, placeholder); //workaround

    // return the new element
    return document.getElementById(id);
}}
```

And I call it here:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    </Provider>, 
    RootUtil.renderRoot("html-root"));
```